# Using grid as field in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, mvvm, data-binding, extjs6, two-way-binding

Binding model property to a form field is pretty easy in ExtJS:

```
// ...skipped everything until fields config for brevity
}, {
  xtype: 'textfield',
  bind: '{modelInstance.someField}'
}, { // ...
```

In this case, `modelInstance` string field `someField` will be synchronized to textbox value, thanks to two way binding. And that is great.

What I want to achieve is to get same kind of behavior in the case when model field is not a string but an array. This is the model:

```
Ext.define('namespace.model.CustomModel', {
  fields: ['easyField', {
    name: 'hardField',
    type: 'auto'  // This will be an array during runtime
  }],
  idProperty: 'easyField'
});
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
// ...skipped everything until fields config for brevity, 
// assume that viewmodel and everything else are set up as expected
}, {
  xtype: 'textfield',
  bind: '{modelInstance.easyField}'
}, {
  xtype: 'gridfield',
  bind: {
    gridArray: '{modelInstance.hardField}'
  }
}, { // ...
```

Understandably, I want `gridfield` component to extend `Ext.grid.Panel` and synchronize its store data to `modelInstance` field `hardField`.

Currently I have this:

```
Ext.define('namespace.form.field.GridField', {
  extends: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
  xtype: 'gridfield',
  // skip requires for brevity
  viewModel: {
    stores: {
      gridFieldItems: {
        type: 'gridfielditems'  // Simple in memory store
      }
    },
    data: {
    }
  },
  store: '{gridFieldItems}',
  // This config enables binding to take place as it creates getters and setters,
  // gridArray is set initially to '{modelInstance.hardField}' as expected
  config: {
    gridArray: null
  },
  // This is necessary for this grid-field component to update 
  // '{modelInstance.hardField}' back in the owners viewModel. 
  publishes: {
    gridArray: true
  },

  // ???
  // bind: {
  //   gridArray: bind gridArray to store data somehow?
  // }

});
```

Here's the problem:

- how do I inject existing `modelInstance.hardField` array as `gridFieldItems` store initial data,
- how do I bind `gridArray` config to store data so that it is updates as we go along cruding the grid,
- do all of these in an elegant MVVM way without writing a bunch of listeners trying to force syncing between JS objects.

Please provide tested solution which is known to work, I already tried a lot of different ways myself, but without success so far.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working fiddle to achieve this binding. The easy way is to bind the array field with "data" attribute of a store. 
A good suggestion on the work you've done is to avoid defining a viewmodel inside a generic component (gridfield) but use viewmodels only on you application specific views. 
On you generic component you should define only configuration attributes with setter/getter/update logics in order to be able to use them with bind. In this case there is no need of custom properties as the store is enough.

**edit**
To avoid the "easy binding" you can implement the set/get logic of the array in your girdfield component. Fore example using the "updateGridArray" method called by the setter and the "datachanged" event of the store.
The fiddle is updated and the example girdfield uses the cell editing plugin to show the 2-way binding.

fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2a3b

```
    Ext.define('Fiddle.model.CustomModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: ['easyField', {
            name: 'hardField',
            type: 'auto' // This will be an array during runtime
        }],
        idProperty: 'easyField'
    });
    Ext.define('Fiddle.fiddleview.CustomViewModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
        alias: 'viewmodel.fiddleview',

        data: {
            currentModel: null
        }
    });
    Ext.define('Fiddle.form.field.GridField', {
        extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
        xtype: 'gridfield',

        config: {
            gridArray: null
        },

        publishes: [
            'selection',
            'gridArray'
        ],

        selModel: 'cellmodel',
        plugins: {
            cellediting: {
                clicksToEdit: 1
            }
        },

        columns: [{
            text: 'Column 1',
            flex: 1,
            editor: true,
            dataIndex: 'field1'
        }],

        initComponent: function () {
            this.store = {
                fields: ['field1'],
                data: [],
                listeners: {
                    scope: this,
                    datachanged: function (store) {
                        this.setGridArray(store.getRange().map(function (record) {
                            return record.getData();
                        }));
                    }
                }
            };

            this.callParent();
        },

        updateGridArray: function (gridArray) {
            this.getStore().suspendEvent('datachanged');
            if (Ext.isEmpty(gridArray)) {
                this.getStore().removeAll();
            } else {
                this.getStore().loadData(gridArray);
            }
            this.getStore().resumeEvent('datachanged');
        }

    });

    var myView = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

        viewModel: 'fiddleview',

        items: [{
            xtype: 'gridfield',
            bind: {
                gridArray: '{currentModel.hardField}'
            }
        }]
    });

    // Bind on model's array to check two-way update
    // It will execute also on cell edit
    myView.getViewModel().bind('{currentModel.hardField}', function (value) {
        window.alert('model\'s array changed');
    });

    // The binding is now active, when the "currentModel" in the viewmodel changes, grid rows are refresched
    myView.getViewModel().set('currentModel', new Fiddle.model.CustomModel({
        hardField: [{
            field1: 'value1'
        }]
    }));
    // Also when data changes in the "currentModel"
    myView.getViewModel().get('currentModel').get('hardField').push({
        field1: 'value2'
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Baron! The idea of binding store data to models field is neat but it is flawed. We have no choice but to update records in original models array rather than in grids store, because store does not push updates back to the model. That means that the grid has to have some knowledge of viewmodel which breaks its genericness. Besides, it does not know how to present add/update views to the user. I'll post my solution later, it's not ideal but it'll ok for the purposes.

Comment: You're right. That was a clean bind only solution. I updated the fiddle with a "gridfield" component that only need the "gridArray" as bindable configuration